# Windows DLL Module Class

Tags: c++, object-oriented, windows

I am doing a project where I use DLL's as run-time modules or plugins. To do this, I use the Windows `LoadLibrary()` and `FreeLibrary()` API calls to call two functions exported by the DLL. I decided to make a class so dealing with the DLL's would be easier. Is there anything I can add to my class to make it better, is there anything I'm doing wrong? Feel free to criticize anything you want.

**SaModule.h**

---

```
#ifndef SAMODULE_H__
#define SAMODULE_H__

#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <exception>
#include "WinException.h"

class SaModule
{
private:

    typedef const char* (*LPFNGETNAME)();
    typedef bool (*LPFNDOSCAN)(std::string&, std::string&);
    HINSTANCE hInstance;
    std::string path;

public:

    SaModule();
    SaModule(const std::string& path);
    ~SaModule();

    void Load(const std::string& path);
    void Unload();

    LPFNDOSCAN DoScan;
    LPFNGETNAME GetName;

    HINSTANCE GetHandle() const;
    operator HINSTANCE() const;

};

#endif//SAMODULE_H__
```

**SaModule.cpp**

---

```
#include "SaModule.h"
#include "WinException.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

SaModule::SaModule(): path(), hInstance(NULL)
{
    //Nothing...
}

SaModule::SaModule(const std::string& path): path(path), hInstance(NULL)
{
    Load(path);
}

SaModule::~SaModule()
{
    Unload();
}

void SaModule::Load(const std::string& path)
{

    this->path = path;

    if( NULL == (hInstance=LoadLibrary(path.c_str())) )
        throw WinException();

    if( NULL == (GetName=reinterpret_cast<LPFNGETNAME>(GetProcAddress(hInstance,"GetName"))) )
        throw WinException();

    if( NULL == (DoScan=reinterpret_cast<LPFNDOSCAN>(GetProcAddress(hInstance, "DoScan"))) )
        throw WinException();

}

void SaModule::Unload()
{
    FreeLibrary(hInstance);
}

HINSTANCE SaModule::GetHandle() const
{
    return hInstance;
}

SaModule::operator HINSTANCE() const
{
    return hInstance;
}
```

**WinException.h**

---

```
#ifndef WINEXCEPTION_H__
#define WINEXCEPTION_H__

#include <Windows.h>
#include <exception>
#include <string>

class WinException: public std::exception
{
private:

    DWORD dwError;
    std::string errMsg;

public:

    WinException();
    const char* what() const;


};

#endif//WINEXCEPTION_H__
```

**WinException.cpp**

---

```
#include "WinException.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

WinException::WinException()
{

    std::ostringstream ss;
    dwError = GetLastError();   
    LPVOID lpMsgBuf = NULL;

    FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER|FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM|FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL, dwError, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL,SUBLANG_DEFAULT), reinterpret_cast<LPTSTR>(&lpMsgBuf), 0, NULL);

    ss << "Error: 0x" << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(8) << dwError << std::endl
        << reinterpret_cast<LPTSTR>(lpMsgBuf);

    errMsg = ss.str();

    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);

}

const char* WinException::what() const
{
    return errMsg.c_str();
}
```

**Example Usage**

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SaModule.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    try
    {
        SaModule mod("some.sa.dll");
        std::cout << "Loaded Module: " << mod.GetName() << std::endl;
    }
    catch( WinException& ex )
    {
        std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: I don't think anyone mentioned this, but those double underscores in `SAMODULE_H__` cause the identifier to infringe upon the reserved ones. Even if you've seen this, read the double underscores part carefully: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a couple of quick thoughts.

1. `DoScan` and `GetName` probably should be initialised to NULL as well.
2. `Load` doesn't call `Unload` for any previous loaded dlls. If Load should be called once only per `SaModule`, that should be detected.
3. A more informative exception could be thrown. "...during attempted insertion of plugin xyz", for example.
4. Beware of function name decoration, if that could be an issue.

Answer (score 3):

First thing that pops out at me:

```
if( NULL == (hInstance=LoadLibrary(path.c_str())) )
```

When programming for Windows, you should almost *never* want to use the "`A`"/"ANSI" versions of functions.  This is legacy from Win9x and you should be using Unicode.  Windows is not like Unix where the C library can assume UTF-8 and everything can keep chugging along with the full set of Unicode chars accesible: by restricting yourself to the "multi-byte" encodings you will (1) see inconsistent behavior depending on what the user sets their language to and (2) not be able to access some Unicode filenames that the user may have on their filesystem.  You should define the `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` macros and use `WCHAR` instead of 8-bit chars.  (Since it seems you want to use the C++ classes I believe `wstring` works instead of `string` here.)

Second:

The `WinException` class looks weird to me.  Not all Windows APIs use `GetLastError` - some of them may return `HRESULT` or do something else.  From that perspective you have not captured the full generality of Windows errors.

I would also say, perhaps controversially since this is not the path everybody has taken, that wrapping Win32 errors with exceptions is a bad idea.  There are some Win32 errors that are not error conditions at all, for example `FindNextFile` will fail with `ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS` when you reach the end of a directory, or I/O will fail with `ERROR_IO_PENDING` to indicate that the I/O is happening asynchronously.  A Win32 program will occasionally have to react to such errors and I would say the way you've done it loses some of that information, or makes it less convenient to work with.

But maybe it's OK for your use.  YMMV.

Comment: Instead of roll-your-own `WinException`, should be using `system_error` and the Windows-specific `system_category` of errors. The best article I've found about this is at [Chris Kohlkoff's blog](http://blog.think-async.com/2010/04/system-error-support-in-c0x-part-1.html).

Comment: @MikeC - Interesting, didn't know about this addition to C++11.  +1

Answer (score 3):

As MikeC suggested, the WinException class could be replaced by [`std::system_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/system_error/system_error). This original came from the [`boost::system`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/system/doc/index.html) library and was included into the C++0x specification with a few changes (mainly some of the names).

**Example for `throw`:**

```
throw std::system_error(std::error_code(::GetLastError(), 
    std::system_category()), "SaModule::Load()");
```

**Example for `catch`:**

```
//...
catch( std::system_error& se )
{
    std::cout << "Error: " << se.code().value() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Message: " << se.code().message() << "\n";
    std::cout << "What: " << se.what() << "\n";
}
```

**Example output for `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`:**

> Error: 2 
>   Message: No such file or directory  
>   What: SaModule::Load()